# Stuck on proving a surface is a cylinder or a plane

Tags: differential-geometry

> A surface with first and second fundamental forms $\mathrm{I}$ and $\mathrm{II}$ whose coefficients(i.e. $E,F,G,L,M,N$ with $\mathrm{I}=Edudu+2Fdudv+Gdvdv,\mathrm{II}=Ldudu+2Mdudv+Ndvdv$) are all constants must be a cylinder or a plane.

I used to think that it's pretty easy. But after trying to differentiate some of them for a while ,I found that I have no idea in solving this. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You can first show that the Gauss curvature is zero, then one of the principle curavature is zero. This forces the surface to be a ruled surface. Whether it is a plane or a cylinder depends on the second principle curvature.

Comment: @John how to show that Gauss curvature is zero?Thanks!

Comment: Gauss curvature can be found using only the first fundamental form, and involves derivative of those $E$, $F$ and $G$. You may find the formula at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianCurvature.html